# How to use useHistory() inside a handleSubmit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a simple (silly) page for a school project, in which i'm making a login page with js, react and bootstrap and I also make API calls. I have this code for the form:

```
render(){
return (
  <div>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="card-body">
      <img src={logo} class="center"></img>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div class="form-group justify-content-center">
           
              <label>Email</label>
              <input class="form-control align-center" type="text" id="example-text-input" placeholder="Email"
              onChange={
                  e=> this.email = e.target.value
              }
              />
              <label>Password</label>
              <input className="form-control" type="password" id="example-text-input" placeholder="*******"
              onChange={
                e=> this.password = e.target.value
              }
              />
            </div>
        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block" ><b>Login</b></button>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
);}
```

And then I have this code to handle the submit (a simple API call that checks the credencials):

```
  handleSubmit = e =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    axios.get('myapilink')
    .then((res)=>{
        var entrou = 0;
        const txt = JSON.stringify(res.data.data);
        const utilizadores = JSON.parse(txt)
        for(var i = 0; i < utilizadores.length; i++)
        {
            if(utilizadores[i].email == this.email){
                if(utilizadores[i].pass == this.password)
                {
                  entrou = 1;
                  /*redirect*/ 
                }
            }
        }
        if(entrou == 0)
        {
            alert('Invalid')
        }
    })
  }
```

Both parts of the code are inside `export default class Formulario extends React.Component`

**The Problem:**

I can't use useHistory() inside the handleSubmit and if I declare `let history = useHistory()` outside of the handleSubmit, I get a syntax error, so I suppose it shouldn't be there... How do I redirect someone if the kogin is correct in this context? (I'm also fairly new to react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both):

> **You can’t use Hooks inside a class component**, but you can definitely mix classes and function components with Hooks in a single tree. Whether a component is a class or a function that uses Hooks is an implementation detail of that component. In the longer term, we expect Hooks to be the primary way people write React components.

If you want to use `useHistory` then you'll need to rewrite your component as a function component.